# postscript example of printing a simple text page

Tags: pdf, tcpdf, postscript

Can someone provide me with an example of (or a link to) a postscript document for printing a simple 1 page (or multiple page) document. I need to use ps2pdf to generate a PDF from postscript since I cannot get TCPDF installed on a server I am using. So my only option is to generate the document in postscript and then send it to ps2pdf. So I am looking for an example of how to print a simple page with text in postscript. If you have another solution for my PDF problem, please let me know.
Thank you

PS:
The system here would not allow me to create the tag "ps2pdf". Can someone with a higher rating please create a tag for "ps2pdf" so it is easier for others to find information in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Are you building a document from scratch or trying to convert an existing document (and if the latter, what is the original format)?

Comment: you mean something like [a2ps](https://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/)?

Comment: For ps2pdf, use the Ghostscript tag.

Answer (score 7):

This is about as simple as you can get. Assuming your default page size for the PostScript converter is 8.5 x 11 (612pt x 792pt) the following PostScript code will print "Hello World" approximately one inch from the upper left of the page in 36 point Times Bold.

```
%!PS
/Times-Bold findfont 36 scalefont setfont
72 684 moveto (Hello World!) show
showpage
```